# What's the best way to heal a scab on top of my dog's head?

Tags: dogs, first-aid

My 6 month old puppy had a bacteria infection which caused a bunch of bumps to form on the top of her head. That is cured now, but from where she had been scratching it looks like one big scab.

What is the best way to get this to heal properly and quickly?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is on-topic or not (community is still deciding on medical questions). I would say you should probably take your dog to the vet and get her fitted with one of those things people fit on dogs heads to keep them from licking, scratching wounds.

Comment: Already have been to the vet, that's how we got the antibiotics to heal the bacterial infection. Err also already have an e-collar. I'm asking what the best thing to do is to get it healed quickly

Comment: Since you have been to the vet, I suspect they have done everything they can to help you and your pet, and I suspect there isn't much to do at this point but wait.

Comment: I shave the hair down.  It get more air and easier to apply ointment.

Answer (score 14):

The solution is simple: **Stop your dog scratching**.

**However,** *implementing* the solution is the challenge.

Basically, every time you're with the dog you want to remain extra vigilant to make sure that she doesn't scratch it, distract her with something.

If you simply don't have the time to hawk eye your dog (as most don't), then it looks like a lampshade collar would be your best bet (they're available at most mid-size pet stores), which are something like:

[image]

My mother's Bichon had one of these in the past when she had a cut on her paw to stop her from licking it and breaking the scab and it is the only really practical and effective way of stopping your dog from scratching the scab.

Comment: We already own an e-collar, she's lived with it on most her life already. Might have to stay using it again :/

Answer (score 8):

I am not a veterinarian.

I have been told by my vet that antibiotic ointment (Neosporin / Polysporin) can be used on a canine cut, as long as:

1. the wound (and therefore the ointment) isn't directly accessible to your dog's mouth (it can be covered with a bandage) and
2. you don't overdo the application of the ointment (I'd say apply a thin coat twice daily).

From your description, the ointment won't be reachable by tongue.  These ointments have been shown to provide slightly accelerated healing for humans on cuts and they can absorb through scabs; these should work just as well for dogs.

If you have further concerns, consult your vet.

Comment: Thanks. We've used neosporin on her before but it doesn't work as well as 100% unpasteurized honey. We may have to go back to using the e-collar with eiher honey or neosporin on a bandage.

Comment: @ElefantPhace sounds like you may need to take her back to the vet

Comment: No it doesn't... Why do you think that?

Answer (score -1):

Keep the buster collar on and try to apply animal friendly moisturiser, and clean off any loose scabs as these cause irritation

Comment: please add more details to your answer to improve it.and take a look here https://pets.stackexchange.com/help on how to give good answers.